# Radix sort in linear time vs. converting input to proper base

Tags: algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

I was thinking about the linear time sorting problem which appears in quite a few sources which prompts you to sort an array of numbers in the range from `0` to `n^3-1` in linear time.

So one way to do this is to use radix sort which normally runs in `O(wn)` where `w` is the max word size by observing that we can obtain word size `3` for any number in that range by using base `n`.

And herein lies my question - while it looks ok on paper, in practice converting all the numbers to base `n` the naive way is going to take quite a lot of time, quite possibly even more than the later sorting itself. Is there any way to convert to base `n` faster than naively or to somehow trick one's way out of this limitation or do you just have to live with it?

Answer (score 2):

One useful observation is that the runtime of this algorithm is the same if you choose as your base not the number n, but the smallest power of two greater than or equal to n. Let's imagine that that number is 2<sup>k</sup>. Now, to read off the base-2<sup>k</sup> digits of a number, you can just inspect blocks of bits of size k in the number, which is doable quite quickly using some bit shifts and logical ANDs. This will likely be fast even if your numbers are stored as variable-length integers, assuming that the variable-length integer uses some nice sort of binary encoding.

Answer (score 0):

There's an ideal size for choosing k bit fields to use 2<sup>k</sup> as the base for radix sort depending on the size of the array, but it doesn't make a lot of difference, less than 10% for choosing r = 8 (1 read pass + 4 radix sort passes), versus r = 16 (1 read pass + 2 radix sort passes), because r = 8 is more cache friendly. On my system, (Intel 2600K 3.4 ghz), for array size = 2^20, r = 8 is slightly fastest. For array size = 2^24, r = 10.67 (using 10,11,11 bit field) is slightly fastest. For array size = 2^26, r = 16 is slightly fastest.

For signed integers, the sign bit can be toggled during the radix sort.

In your case, the max value of an integer is given, so this would help in choosing the bit field sizes.